# Npm Install ERR! message

Tags: npm, npm-install

npm ERR! code ENOENT

npm ERR! syscall open

npm ERR! path /Users/giovanylopes/bootcamp-projects/react-nodejs-example/package.json

npm ERR! errno -2

npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/Users/giovanylopes/bootcamp-projects/react-nodejs-example/package.json'

npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.

npm ERR! enoent

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:

npm ERR!     /Users/giovanylopes/.npm/_logs/2022-11-18T14_26_47_519Z-debug-0.log

I was expecting to install all the dependencies that are defined in the package.json file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most probably you don't have a `package.json` file in  `/Users/giovanylopes/bootcamp-projects/react-nodejs-example/` directory.

Comment: I did ls command and got this : Dockerfile api my-app package-lock.json

Comment: So as you can see there is no `package.json` file in your directory. You only can run `npm install` in a directory where you have `packge.json`.

Comment: I see okay... sorry I'm a complete newbie how do I  do that?

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to do. Are you trying to run a nodejs API? Then look inside your `api` directory. You might have a package.json file there.

Comment: I cd'ed into api and tried npm install and it installed the dependencies. So I think it worked!

Answer (score 0):

The part of the error that you have posted to focus on is the following piece:

> ```
> no such file or directory, open '/Users/giovanylopes/bootcamp-projects/react-nodejs-example/package.json'
> ```

It can't find your `package.json` file at the location it has listed.  Take a look at that location and make sure that you have a `package.json` file there.

Comment: I did ls command and got this :

Dockerfile  api   my-app   package-lock.json

Comment: Use the full path to make sure:
`ls /Users/giovanylopes/bootcamp-projects/react-nodejs-example/package.json`

Comment: ls: /Users/giovanylopes/bootcamp-projects/react-nodejs-example/package.json: No such file or directory